# How to swap first and last digit in number in c++

Tags: c++

I don't understand why the following code always answers with `0`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n,a,b;
    cin>>n;
    b=n%10;

    while(n!=0) {
        a=n%10;
        n=n/10;     
    }
    a=b;
    b=a;
    cout<<n<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the only change you make to `n` is `n=n/10` in a loop until `n==0`, so it will always print 0.

Comment: What are you expecting to print?

Comment: I know but what can i do to swap first and last digit?

Comment: @BarishNamazov it is probably the easiest to convert `n` to a string, then swap the digits, and parse it again to an integer.

Comment: @Wimmel I have to do it with integer without string,thanks for comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To swap two numbers, you need a temporary register

```
tmp=a;
a=b;
b=tmp;
```

However, if you are trying to swap digits in `n`, you need to change `n`. Which you have destroyed in your loop. Keep a copy of it beforehand?

Or simply note that `floor(log(n)/log(10))` gives you the power of 10 for the first digit.

```
n=23456;
int firstdec = pow(10,floor(log(n)/log(10))); // eg 10000
int firstdig = n/firstdec; // eg 2
int lastdig  = n%10; // eg 6
int removed  = ((n-firstdig*firstdec)/10)*10 ; // eg 3450
int final    = removed + lastdig*firstdec + firstdig; // eg 63452
```

Comment: Ok,how can i repair my loop?

Comment: you don't need a loop!

Comment: Thanks very much, i will do it, but is there a way with loop?

Comment: Yes, you need to keep a count of how many times you went through the loop. That tells you the position (i.e. power of 10) for the first digit. Then after the loop, you can use that power of 10 to subtract off the first digit and last digit, and add back the new first and last digits.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
a=b;
b=a;
```

looks nice.
Do you mean `swap(a, b)` or

```
int t = a;
a = b;
b = t;
```

?

And you're not actually changing `n`.

Comment: I wanted swap what can i do

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, swno;
    int fd, ld, digits;

    // Reads a number from user
    cout<<"Enter any number:";
    cin>>num;

    ld = num % 10; //Gets last digit
    digits = (int)log10(num); //Total number of digits - 1
    fd = (int)(num / pow(10, digits)); //Gets the first digit

    swno = ld;
    swno *= (int)pow(10, digits);
    swno += num % ((int)pow(10, digits));
    swno -= ld;
    swno += fd;

    cout<<"\nOriginal number = "<<num;
    cout<<"\nNumber after swapping first and last digit: "<<swno;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code has some problems, like the variable swap. But also, you seem to expect that by changing `a` and `b`, `n` is changed accordingly, which is not going to happen.

First, because `a` and `b` are not references to the digits, they are mere copies. Second, you destroyed you `n` in the `loop` finding `a`, so even when you fix you swap the code will still print `0`.

My recommendation is to convert the integer to a string, change the first and last, and then convert it back. It will be much simpler and more readable.

In order to do that you should take a look at `stringstream`s.

Comment: Thanks,but I have to do it with integer

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    
    int a;
    char k,l;
    cin>>a;
    string s=to_string(a);
    k=s[0];
    l=s[s.length()-1];
    s[0]=l;
    s[s.length()-1]=k;
    cout<<s;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is what is missing in your code. real= entered value, first and last digits = firstd and lastd and i = number of digits of the entered number.

```
real -= lastd;
    real += firstd;
    real -= (firstd*i);
    real += (lastd*i);
```

Comment: The op has a basic logic problem using the while loop.

Comment: This example would be better if you explained where you got real, firstd, lastd and i.